# Prove that if $a$, $b$, and $n$ are positive integers such that $a^n|b^n$ then $a|b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing

This is how I did it, but not sure if it is a correct proof.

Assume that $a^n | b^n$.  Then $(a^n, b^n) = a^n$.
So, 
$$b^n = a^n(p_1p_2p_3...p_k)^n$$
$$b^n = (ap_1p_2p_3...p_k)^n$$
$$b = ap_1p_2p_3...p_k$$

Which implies that $(a, b) = a \implies a|b$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From $a^n\mid b^n$ you can deduce $b^n=a^n\,c$, but you do not know that $c=m^n$ for some integer $m$. In fact, is what you are trying to prove.

Strategy: prove that if $p$ is a prime and $p^\alpha\mid a$, then divides $p^\alpha\mid b$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Then $a=dx$, and $b=dy$, where $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime. We will show that $x=1$.

We are told that $a^n$ divides $b^n$. So $b^n=qa^n$ for some integer $q$.
Thus $d^ny^n=qd^n x^n$, and therefore $y^n=qx^n$.

It follows that $x^n$ divides $y^n$.

Suppose that $x\ne 1$. Then $x$ is divisible by some prime $p$. It follows that $p$ divides $y^n$, and therefore $p$ divides $y$. This contradicts the fact that $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime.